# how do i add elements to a list with model type

Tags: java, jersey, multipartform-data, apache-commons

I am new to java. I want to add an element to a list.

```
List<RequestAttachmentDTO> attachments
```

RequestAttachmentDTO class is here,

```
public class RequestAttachmentDTO {

    byte[] contentStream;
    String fileName;
    String contentType;
    String contentTransferEncoding;


    public RequestAttachmentDTO(byte[] contentStream, String fileName, String contentType) {
        this.contentStream = contentStream;
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.contentType = contentType;
    }

    public RequestAttachmentDTO(byte[] contentStream, String fileName, String contentType,String contentTransferEncoding) {
        this.contentStream = contentStream;
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.contentType = contentType;
        this.contentTransferEncoding=contentTransferEncoding;
    }

    public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }

    public String getContentType() {
        return contentType;
    }

    public byte[] getContentStream() {
        return contentStream;
    }

    public String getContentTransferEncoding() {
        return contentTransferEncoding;
    }

}
```

This is how i tried to add,

```
String fieldName = item.getFieldName();
            String fiileName = FilenameUtils.getName(item.getName());
            fileContent = item.getInputStream();                
            Path path = Paths.get("/data/uploads/form_urlencoded_simple_decoded_body.txt");
            byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);

            List<RequestAttachmentDTO> attachments = new ArrayList<>();
            attachments.add(data,fieldName,"application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

It is not accepting it.

PS:- The file `item` is taken as an upload from a JSP page in `multipart/form-data` encoding.

Can you help me to add elements to this list. Thank you.

Comment: "String fiileName =" ... is there a typo in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Java!

Currently you are not creating an object of `RequestAttachmentDTO`, to do that you need to invoke this constructor `RequestAttachmentDTO(byte[] contentStream, String fileName, String contentType)` with proper values.

So to fix this issue change this `attachments.add(data,fieldName,"application/x-www-form-urlencoded");` line to `attachments.add(new RequestAttachmentDTO(data,fieldName,"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));`

Comment: Thank you very much :) :) for the detailed anser.